# GitHub credentials not saved in IntelliJ

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I want to share various projects on github.com via IntelliJ, CLion or PyCharm and I could not do that.

If I want to share a project on a repository on GitHub or create a repository on that programs, the following error occurs: **IntelliJ**, **CLion** or **PyCharm** do **not save credentials information** from GitHub.

It does not matter if I use the username and password login or the token login. Reinstalling e. g. IntelliJ and git did not help too.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing `gnome-keyring` worked for my kubuntu system.

Comment: Definitely not helpful at all, consider providing a link or something

Comment: just enter in terminal `sudo apt-get install gnome-keyring`